# Excel VBA - Conditionally add inputs to array for analysis

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

All, I only have a very basic knowledge of VBA and haven't worked much with arrays/matrices.  I'm trying to do something like the script outline below.  Basically, I'd like a function that inputs a range of cells, and adds values to the array if they meet some conditions (in this case <>0).  Then, the function will find the skew of the array.  If there are no values in the array or if there is an error, the function returns 0.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
Function array_analysis(array_input As Range)

Dim my_array As Variant
Dim skew As Double

For Each i In array_input

    If array_input(i).Value <> 0 Then
        'add value to my_array
    End If
Next i

'if array is empty array_analysis = 0

skew = Application.WorksheetFunction.skew(my_array)

array_analysis = skew

End Function
```

[image: picture of data]

Comment: Look at ReDim Preserve, or consider using a Collection or Dictionary object, and then adding the resultant values to the array. I'd probably use an `ArrayList` for this project. Or if you have O365, do it with worksheet functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calculate Skew From Range

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function calculateSkewFromRange(InputRange As Range) As Double

    ' Write values from Input Range to Input Array ('InputData').

    Dim InputData As Variant
    If InputRange.Rows.Count > 1 Or InputRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        ' Input Range contains multiple cells.
        InputData = InputRange.Value
    Else
        ' Input Range contains only one cell.
        ReDim InputData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        InputData(1, 1) = InputRange.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Input Array to Skew Array ('SkewData').

    Dim SkewData As Variant
    ReDim SkewData(1 To UBound(InputData, 1) * UBound(InputData, 2))

    Dim CurrentValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(InputData, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(InputData, 2)
            CurrentValue = InputData(i, j)
            If VarType(CurrentValue) = vbDouble Then
                If CurrentValue <> 0 Then
                    k = k + 1
                    SkewData(k) = InputData(i, j)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Calculate Skew.

    If k > 0 Then
        ' Data found.
        ReDim Preserve SkewData(1 To k)
        calculateSkewFromRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.skew(SkewData)
    Else
        ' No data found.
        calculateSkewFromRange = 0
    End If

End Function

Sub testCalculateSkewFromRange()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Columns("A")
    Debug.Print calculateSkewFromRange(rng)
End Sub
```

Comment: that worked perfectly!  Thanks very much, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**`Skew()` function with non-zero data**

Using Office 365 you can code as follows to calculate only with non-zero data:

```
Function array_analysis(rng As Range)
'Purp.: get only data <> 0 (in contiguous range)
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    'get non zero data
    Dim NonZeroData
    NonZeroData = Evaluate("=Filter(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "<>0" & ","""")")
    'return function result
    On Error Resume Next
    array_analysis = .skew(NonZeroData)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then array_analysis = 0: Err.Clear
End With
End Function
```

*Just in addition to @RonRosenfeld 's comments:*

If you don't dispose of O365 you could redimension a temporary array `temp` with the range's rows count (as maximum), increment a new counter (e.g. `ii = ii + 1`) for all cell conditions <> zero then adding a new `temp` element indexed by `ii`, and redim eventually to `ii` to get the non-zero data.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I tried your code exactly as you outlined, except with an indent for the "With" section.  It returned #VALUE! in every cell.

Comment: What is your data range - can you edit a sample or picture? @JoeJackson1234

Comment: Did you take note of the `.` prefix before `skew`, i.e. `array_analysis = .skew(NonZeroData)` ? @JoeJackson1234

Comment: thanks again for your help, I made the changes but the still results in a 0 value or "-" for every entry for the function.  I also pasted a picture of the data as an edit into my original question.

Comment: I get -1.221374067 as function result for the indicated cells in cell `J117`. Are the cells marked by `-` contain anything other than formatted zeros? @JoeJackson1234